# What is the real definition of density?

Tags: mass, definition, density, volume

What does [density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density) really mean? Everyone just provides me with the equation of finding density whenever I ask this question.

Comment: Mass per unit volume, or is there some trick here?  It's derived from mass and length , so it needs the equation.

Comment: @MartinJames A quantity defined as A/B is called ‘quotient of A by B’ or ‘A per B’, but not ‘A per unit B’.

Comment: @Loong In this case "unit volume" is his B in the 'A per B' format.  It's a very common wording in physics.

Comment: What does "really" really mean? Why does the equation that everybody provides fail to satisfy your curiosity? If you can figure that out, then maybe you can turn it in to a question you can ask here that readers will be able to answer for you.

Comment: P.S., Don't be surprised when physicists answer questions with math. That's what physics _is_: It's all about using math to describe the universe.

Answer (score 1):

It means nothing more than the amount of mass contained in the unit volume of a given material. So if a material is denser, one cubic meter (or cup or soda can or cubic feet...) of it is heavier.